# How to fix 'Identity Provider not found' error when using OpenAM?

Tags: openam

I am trying to set up the OpenWIS software. In Fedora 28, I have deployed OpenAM 12.0.0 on tomcat 7.0.59 which is run as root.

I have also deployed another webapp called openwis-user-portal on another instance of tomcat 7.0.59 which is run as a different user called openwisuser. In the OpenAM instance, I imported the openam and openwis-user-portal as hosted Identity Provider and hosted Service Provider respectively and put them in the same circle of trust using protocol SAMLv2.

I deployed and configured another webapp called idpdiscovery on the first tomcat instance too.

But when I try to login in the openwis user portal, it gives the following error in the log file:

> "Identity Provider not found."

Have I missed something to do?

Comment: If the message is shown on the OpenWIS side of things, then it's rather an OpenWIS question rather than an OpenAM one. OpenWIS would need to send an SAML AuthnRequest to OpenAM-based SAML IdP. If you have only one IdP, then normaly you do not need IdP Discovery.

Comment: Also, it seems to me you want “openwis-user-portal” to be a //remote// SP, not a hosted SP, if you expect OpenWIS to send SAML2 requests to OpenAM.

Comment: I changed the openwis-user-portal from hosted SP to remote SP. Now the error is: `Service Provider id is null.`

Comment: How do you initialize the SSO request (SP-initiated? IdP-initiated?)? You might be missing a metaAlias specified somewhere. Take a look at OpenAM logs for more information.